# Realm Methods in a Nested Loop Throw "Will Never Be Execute" Warning in Swift

Tags: swift, realm

UPDATED ****

THIS PROBLEM WAS NOT RELATED TO NESTED LOOPS OR REALM.  I DECLARED A VARIABLE IN THE WRONG LOCATION.

I am using Realm in a project and am getting a warning when I call out to Realm inside a nested loop.  On the write method below the warning is called.

```
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let fetchedArticles = realm.objects(Article.self)

        for article in fetchedArticles
        {
            // Test for 30 Articles
            var iArticleNumber = 0

            if iArticleNumber < 30
            {
                // Do nothing
            }
            else if iArticleNumber >= 30
            {
                try! realm.write // ** WARNING IS THROWN HERE ON WRITE **
                {
                    realm.delete(article)
                }
            }

            iArticleNumber += 1
        }
```

If I remove the if-else code I do not get the error.

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let fetchedArticles = realm.objects(Article.self)

try! realm.write
{
    realm.delete(fetchedArticles[0])
}
```

Can someone help me understand why and how to get the error to go away?

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with Realm or *nested* loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring iArticleNumber inside the loop. It's never going to go past 1 because it resets every iteration. Just move the declaration outside the loop

Alternatively... Don't use your own counter. There's a perfectly useable for variation for this purpose.

```
for (iArticleNumber, article) in fetchedArticles.enumerated() {
    print("Item \(iArticleNumber): \(article)")
}
```

Comment: Haha, that's embarrassing.  Thanks for the help.  I should have seen that long before I posted this.